# Create a field with conditional values based on other fields in SQL

Tags: sql, dbt

I have a table like this:

| ID | Revenue_Tom | Revenue_John | Revenue_Lisa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 0 | 257 | 138 |
| aab | 376 | 0 | 0 |

And I need to create a table where the ID field is the value of the old ID + the name of the field where it has no 0 values.
If an ID has more than 2 fields with non-zero values, I need to create 2 new IDs separately, and I need the Revenue field to be the value of the old revenue that has been considerated in each case.

That would be the expected output (It's a bit hard to explain, I think the expected output is more self-explicative):

| ID2 | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| aaa_John | 257 |
| aaa_Lisa | 138 |
| aab_Tom | 376 |

(I'm doing this in DBT which uses SQL+Jinja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create 3 queries and join the with union all you will have your result.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ID,'_Tom') ID2
   Revenue_Tom Revenue
FROM table_name
WHERE Revenue_Tom > 0
   UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(ID,'_John') ID2
   Revenue_John
FROM table_name
WHERE Revenue_John > 0
   UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(ID,'_Lisa') ID2
   Revenue_Lisa
FROM table_name
WHERE Revenue_Lisa > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful!!